# Existence of an increasing sequence such that the limit of a continuous function exists and it is 0

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have a continuous function such that its limsup for $t \to \infty$ is $1$ and its liminf for $t \to \infty$ is $-1$. How can i justify the existence of a discrete increasing sequence such that on this sequence the function converges to $0$?

Comment: Hint: Intermediate value theorem

Comment: @Desperado With this theorem I can prove that this function assumes all values in $(-1,1)$ but how can i prove that there is a discrete sequence on which the limit is 0?

Comment: Well, you have two sequences $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)$ converging to $\infty$, such that $f(x_n) \to 1$ and $f(y_n) \to -1$, hence by the IVT there is a sequence $(z_k)_k \to \infty$ with $f(z_k)=0$.